# What is the best method for creating a mobile app

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have been creating RIA type apps now for many years and I am very comfortable working with the flex frame work. However I have never created an AIR app.
With that being said I have a killer mobile device game I want to create, but have no idea on what is best methods to publish or best SDKs or IDEs.
So I guess I have a few questions.
Whats the best IDE to use for open source like flash develop or just go with flex builder?
I will assume 4.5 flex SDK would be best?
And where can I find a decent tutorial on setting up and publishing of the apps. For now just android based tutorials. I figure I can get into the IOS mess later.
My Google ninja skills seem to be failing me as all I can get via Google are game links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have enough experience to say if Flash is the best choice for mobile devices. That's the only tech I used. Our library of games/apps here were almost Flash/Flex only so it was the logical choice.

Know that there are some perfomance issues with Flash compiled for mobile: vector rendering is costly, GPU mode can't render filters, etc. There are a bunch of documentation on this ([exemple](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/optimize_content_ios.html))

As for the IDE, I only used Flash Builder but FDT or Flash Develop should be fine, as long as the correct parameters are passed to the compiler you'll be able to build for mobile.

As for the Flex SDK, latest version is 4.6 and that should be the one to use IF YOU NEED FLEX. Flex apps takes longer to init but offers interesting things on mobile such as View based navigation and native text. Pure Flash is more lighweight in term of file size and is faster to compile. If you dont' need an RIA like interface for your game, you might consider not using Flex at all.

You'll have to use AIR for mobile : captive runtime only for iOS, optional for Android. Captive runtime means the AIR runtime is embedded in the app (bigger apps but no dependance on an external app). Current SDK version is 3.1.

Tutorials on how to setup your project will depend on wich IDE you'll be using. Then just look for something like "[IDE] Flash mobile project setup".

Finally, I advise you start on iOS THEN get on Android later. There are many devices for Android and you might end up having a hard time with a bug that happens on one device only and not on others, and vice versa. iOS is more standardized, so that way you can manage exceptions at a later time.

As an interesting note, I'd also like to point out the fact that it's impossible to allow code import when dynamically loading external SWF on iOS. You'll have to export them to SWC and make instances of your objects instead (it's a lot cleaner that way anyway).

Comment: Good answer. I'd like to add that Flex on iPad 1 is slow. You can see that interface is not running smoothly even with simple apps. Also Flex components don't support multi-touch. Personally I wouldn't develop mobile apps using Flex. Take a look at AIR 3.2 with Stage3D support. At least now we can make decent games.

Comment: Wow people around here really jump on closing threads. Thank you for the answer. Not sure my accept will hold since they closed it.

Answer (score 1):

I have been building mobile applications with Flex 4.6 / Air on FlashBuilder and it is a joy to use. Check out Air 3.2 rc1, which was released today: it includes hardware accelerated 3D graphics. If you want to build games, I would recommend the Starling framework (which takes advantage of Stage3D)

Comment: Thank. The games I have in mind are top down types. So for now I don't think I will need that, but I will look into it.